# Run Dash plotly after click button

Tags: django, django-views, plotly, plotly-dash, htmx

let's say I have a dashboard that contains many information and plots.

I have a dropdown list that generates Plots and another dropdown list named Wells.

I have a plot that I created with dash and it works very fine but with a fixed input!

and also dash plots this plot at starting the page :( !

My question is how to prevent dash to plot directly and execute after I press a button that takes the selected item from the Wells list and callback the function and replots.

so this is my HTML page :

```
<div class="col-md-3" >
<select class="custom-select mb-4" name="Wells" hx-get="{% url 'addplotly' %}" hx-trigger="change" hx-target="#plotly_production" hx-include="[name='Toggle']">
    <option selected>Select Well</option>
    {% for well in TFTWells %}
    <option value="{{well.WellID}}">{{well.WellID}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</div>
```

and this is my dash script:

```
app = DjangoDash('Pressure_guage', external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(
    id="dark-light-theme",
    children=[
        html.Div([html.H3("Pressure Control", style={"textAlign": "center"}),], className="row"),

        html.Div([
                html.Div(
                    daq.Gauge(
                        #size=150,
                        color={"gradient":True,"ranges":{"green":[0,the_maxCSG/3],"yellow":[the_maxCSG/3,the_maxCSG*6/7],"red":[the_maxCSG*6/7,the_maxCSG]}},
                        id="my-daq-gauge1", min=0, max=the_maxCSG, value=PRES_CSG, label="CSG "+str(PRES_CSG)+" bar",style={'display': 'inline-block'}
                    ),
                    className="three columns",
                ),
                html.Div(
                    daq.Gauge(
                        #size=150,
                        color={"gradient":True,"ranges":{"green":[0,the_max/3],"yellow":[the_max/3,the_max*6/7],"red":[the_max*6/7,the_max]}},
                        id="my-daq-gauge2", min=0, max=the_max, value=PRES_TBG, label="TBG "+str(PRES_TBG)+" bar",style={'display': 'inline-block'}
                    ),
                    className="three columns",
                ),
                html.Div(
                    daq.Gauge(
                        #size=150,
                        color={"gradient":True,"ranges":{"green":[0,the_maxAVD/3],"yellow":[the_maxAVD/3,the_maxAVD*6/7],"red":[the_maxAVD*6/7,the_maxAVD]}},
                        id="my-daq-gauge3", min=0, max=the_maxAVD, value=PRES_AVD, label="AVD",style={'display': 'inline-block'}
                    ),
                    className="three columns",
                ),
                html.Div(
                    daq.Gauge(
                        color={"gradient":True,"ranges":{"green":[0,the_maxGL/3],"yellow":[the_maxGL/3,the_maxGL*6/7],"red":[the_maxGL*6/7,the_maxGL]}},
                        id="my-daq-gauge4", min=0, max=the_maxGL, value=RESEAU_GL, label="GL",style={'display': 'inline-block'}
                    ),
                    className="three columns",
                ),
            ],
            className="row",
        ),
    ],
)
```

[image]

So how I could do this using a button and callback that takes the well name?

Comment: The answer is to use callback with Input(component_id='button',... )

Comment: it is not clear to me, I'd searched about this Input, but I didn't get the idea!